# C++ custom STL vector instantiation error

Tags: c++, vector, stl, instantiation

I'm in the process of writing my own, slightly weaker version of STL (it doesn't support Allocators at present).

The most important bit here is this:

```
template <typename T>
class vector
{
public:
  typedef T                                value_type;
  typedef value_type&                      reference;
  typedef const value_type&                const_reference;
  typedef random_access_iterator<T>        iterator;
  typedef random_access_iterator<const T>  const_iterator;
  typedef unative_t                        size_type;
  typedef native_t                         difference_type;
  typedef value_type*                      pointer;
  typedef const value_type*                const_pointer;

  vector(const size_type n = 0) : vector<T>(n, T()) { }

  vector(const size_type n, const T& val) : m_capacity(n == 0 ? 100 : n * 2),
                                        m_size(n), m_data(new T[m_capacity])
  {
    for (decltype(m_size) i = 0; i < m_size; ++i)
      m_data[i] = val;
  }

  // fancy declarations go here...
private:
  size_type m_capacity; // Where size_type is the unsigned word size of the CPU
  size_type m_size;     // for my computer, this is the equivalent of uint64_t.
  pointer m_data;       // At present, pointer is T*
}
```

Now I'm on Mint 15, compiling with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror # gcc-4.8.1
```

and the implementation file is:

```
#include "structures/vector.hpp"
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  vector<int> vi;                   // compiles okay
  vector<float> vf(10);             // compiles okay
  vector<double> vd1(100, 30.0);    // compiles okay
  std::vector<double> vd2(100, 30); // compiles okay
  vector<double> vd2(100, 30);      // error: undefined reference to
                                    // vector<double>::vector<int>(int, int)
  return 0;
}
```

I've tried sifting through std::vector from GCC 4.8.1, but it turned up very little. The only real difference I can see is that I'm not using an allocator, but that shouldn't have an impact on the instantiation of the class!

Although I've only given relevant information, this is all I've implemented so far. When writing template classes, I tend to take advantage of the lazy instantiation rule and test everything as I write it (it's slower, but at least I know everything works).

Any help greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

cjdb01

Comment: You may try `vector<double> vd2(100, (double)30);`

Comment: I'd prefer my implementation be as transparent as STL. All for explicit casting, but I do want to know why I'd need to go `vector<double> vd2(100, static_cast<double>(30));` when the STL equivalent doesn't.

Comment: The error points to a templated constructor, but your code does not show it. Are you sure those are all the constructors you have?

Comment: Funny, when I run that code with that same command line I get _completely_ different errors: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecd696f0c99b380b

Answer (score 2):

The posted code, after fixing various missing details, e.g., the necessary `typedef`s for `size_type` and `pointer` and adding a default constructor, does compile and link. Given that there was another constructor missing and based on your error, I'd be pretty sure there is another constructor looking something like this:

```
template <typename S>
vector(size_type, S); // not, yet, defined
```

You want to provide an implementation for this constructor.

Comment: I've put my default constructor in the code above (I copied and pasted from my template file, which isn't where my interface is defined, so default values weren't copied across) and the error still arises.

How will adding what you've suggested fix the problem and what do you suggest it should do? I'm thinking delegate to the main constructor, vector(const size_type, const T&).

Comment: @cjdb01: Yes, the default constructor isn't the issue: the not shown templatized constructor is! The default constructor is just a clear indication that you didn't post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) but something else.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like your problem is that you're redefining vd2.

std::vector **vd2**(100, 30); // compiles okay

vector **vd2**(100, 30);      // error: undefined reference to